# Outlook 2010 (purchased copy) Reminders alerting to Days in the future

Tags: microsoft-outlook, reminder

I purchased my Outlook 2010 via Office 2010.  Recently, the Reminders have been alerting me to things that are going to be due in the next several days or weeks.  Previously, it only alerted me to something that was coming up in the near future or was over due.  Any idea how to get it to stop telling me about something that is coming in two weeks?

Answer (score 2):

File > Options.. In dialog box open Calendar tab. There is a setting "Default Reminders". It's default is 15 minutes. But maybe you accidentally changed this to 4 days, 2 weeks or something else...

Comment: thanks guys.  it seems to be okay now.  i have the reminders set to 15 minutes.  if it comes up again, i will check to see what the reminders are set to.  i appreciate your help!  happy new year!! chip

Comment: if this was your solution please accept the answer so the question will disappear from unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 1):

What did you set under "reminder" on the create appointment window? (Middle top of screenshot)
[image]